# PHP query, get results for the last 7 days ("complete" days)

Tags: sql

I have this query, which output number of rows per day for the last 7 days.
How do I change it, so I only get "complete days"? meaning: results from today will not be counted (since today is not "finished").

```
SELECT date(downloaddate), COUNT(id) AS num_downloads, 
       SUM(filesize) AS daily_filesize
FROM downloads 
WHERE downloaddate > now() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK 
GROUP BY date(downloaddate)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `curdate()`. Unlike `now()` it doesn't include the time so you are effectively comparing `downloaddate` against today's date with time of '00:00:00' (start of day).

ie.

```
SELECT date(downloaddate), COUNT(id) AS num_downloads, 
    SUM(filesize) AS daily_filesize 
FROM downloads 
WHERE downloaddate < CURDATE() 
    AND downloaddate > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK 
GROUP BY date(downloaddate)
```

Comment: +1 Though you should probably use `curdate()` instead of `now()` in the second part of the `where` statement.  With `now()` you get only half of the first day.

Comment: @Andomar, good point I hadn't considered the second part of the `WHERE`.

Answer (score 2):

You're already using `date()` to get the date part.  Extend it's use into the `where` clause, or use `curdate()` as a shorthand for `date(now())`, like:

```
WHERE    downloaddate BETWEEN curdate()
                      AND curdate() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

This will grab 7 whole days, ending last midnight.